# c# While Loop issues

Tags: c#, debugging, while-loop, keyboard-events

```
    while (TOGGLE == false) {

            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A)) { RESULT = RESULT + "A";}
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.B)) { RESULT = RESULT + "B"; MessageBox.Show(RESULT); }
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.C)) { RESULT = RESULT + "C"; MessageBox.Show(RESULT); }
    }
```

Ok, so when I click the B or C key everything works fine and it adds the word to the string variable RESULT but when I click in A it will add an infinite amount of A's to the RESULT string. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I am aware that I am not setting TOGGLE to false. But that is the point! I'll explain better: This app will be running in the background. So when the client writes in notepad this program will detect every single key that he pressed and add it to the RESULT string. I don't want this while loop to stop as soon as a key is pressed. I want it to loop until the client is done writing in notepad (that's when I set TOGGLE to false).

Comment: You are not changing `TOGGLE` value anywhere in your code, even on pressing `B`, it should continue *infinitely* after displaying the message box.

Comment: when do you change the `TOGGLE`?

Comment: That is what is known as an infinite loop.  Since you are popping up a `MessageBox` when you press `b` or `c`, it will display the `RESULT` after only one character is added to the message.  When pressing `a`, it will add an `A` to the message repeatedly as long as the key is down.

Comment: Is it WinForm or WPF application? Anyway, you should probably rely on the control events instead of the inifite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are blocking the loop when the message box appears, but for A no message box is there to prevent the ui thread from continuing around the loop while the A key is still pressed down.

You need to

```
break;
```

out of the loop after you append your string, or display a message box, depending on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

When you show a message box, it stops the while loop from continuing because the call to the message box is a blocking call. Meaning that code will not continue to execute until the messagebox is closed.

In your example, when you press A the message box is not shown, so the loop continues. To solve this, you must set `Toggle` to true.

```
while (TOGGLE == false) 
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A)) 
    { 
        RESULT = RESULT + "A";
        TOGGLE = true;
    }
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.B)) 
    { 
        RESULT = RESULT + "B"; 
        MessageBox.Show(RESULT);
        TOGGLE = true;
    }
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.C)) 
    {
        RESULT = RESULT + "C"; 
        MessageBox.Show(RESULT); 
        TOGGLE = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is going VERY VERY fast.  Pressing the "A" key for one second mean it will be press for a couple thousand loop cycles. Adding a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);` will hang the loop a little.

Maybe this could help you achieve what you want:

```
while (TOGGLE == false)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A)) { RESULT = RESULT + "A"; System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); }
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.B)) { RESULT = RESULT + "B"; MessageBox.Show(RESULT); }
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.C)) { RESULT = RESULT + "C"; MessageBox.Show(RESULT); }
}
```

Another solution without a Thread.Sleep

```
DateTime lastAletter = DateTime.Now;
while (TOGGLE == false)
{
     if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A) && lastAletter.AddMilliseconds(100) < DateTime.Now) { RESULT = RESULT + "A"; lastAletter = DateTime.Now; }
     if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.B)) { RESULT = RESULT + "B"; MessageBox.Show(RESULT); }
     if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.C)) { RESULT = RESULT + "C"; MessageBox.Show(RESULT); }
 }
```

Using a `KeyPress event` would be a lot more efficient and remember that a `while(true)` is processor hungry

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that too but isn't using Sleep a bit buggy (in this particular case)?

Comment: You need to consider that while sleeping nothing will be "registered", but using a loop for this kind of thing is a little processor hungry... you should try to register on a KeyPress Event or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that I am not setting TOGGLE to false. But that is the point! I'll explain better: This app will be running in the background. So when the client writes in notepad this program will detect every single key that he pressed and add it to the RESULT string. I don't want this while loop to stop as soon as a key is pressed. I want it to loop until the client is done writing in notepad (that's when I set TOGGLE to false).